# Showing the date sales were first above 0

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report that has sales by week with the start date of every week. I want to create a column that shows the date where the sales are first above zero to denote the week that store first started trading, such as:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxoCE.jpg

Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will make a group on StoreId.

For the Site Open expression use Min function combined with and Iif that checks when sales value is above zero. The "StoreId" in the expression is the group name

```
= Min(Iif(Fields!Sales.Value>0, Fields!StartDate.Value, Nothing), "StoreId")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!